# аналитика - каждая сессия отдельно

Tags: android, ios

Добрый день!
Есть ли какие-то решения для того чтобы при аналитике мобильных приложений смотреть отдельно каждую сессию?

Google analytics и прочие предлагают общую статистику: 1000 вошло, из них 300 отвалилось 300 перешло туда и т.д.
А очень хочется просто взять конкретную сессию пользователя и смотреть как/куда он переходит и на что кликает.

Нашел одну такую - appsee, даже видео сессии снимается, но дорого. Может есть что-то похожее?

Comment: по моему Flurry что то такое умеет. И в Crashlytics 'Answers' посмотрите